# I am making a script in roblox studioi fto make the player have an animation when a tool is equipped but it is not working

Tags: lua, roblox

here is the script please help me

```
local gun =  script.Parent
local player = nil
local char =  nil
local mouse =  nil
local connection =  nil
local carryAnim = script.Parent:WaitForChild("M16Carry")
local carryTrack = nil

local function doAnimations(char, equipped)
    local hum = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    local animator = hum:WaitForChild("Animator")
    
    if equipped then
        carryTrack = animator:LoadAnimation(carryAnim)
        carryTrack:Play()
    elseif carryTrack then
        carryTrack:Stop()
        carryTrack:Destroy()
    end
end


local function onActivated()

end

local function onEquipped()
    player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
    mouse = player:GetMouse()
    connection = gun.Activated:Connect(onActivated)
    char = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
    doAnimations(char, true)
end

local function onUnequipped()
    player = nil
    mouse = nil
    connection:Disconnect()
    doAnimations(char, false)
end

gun.Equipped:Connect(onEquipped)
gun.Unequipped:Connect(onUnequipped)
```

i still cannot find the problem can you help me find it-Roblox studio (i need this part so i can submit this question ejkeoodeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeedddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee)